# Are runes still useful in a no-powers playthrough?

Tags: dishonored-2

I'm playing as Emily and decided to reject the Outsider's offer of powers. I've picked up at least one rune since then, maybe two, but I haven't seen any UI section where I can spend these runes to upgrade anything.

Is it missing because I went with the no-powers option and runes only upgrade power-related things, or am I just blind and missing the screen that lets me upgrade abilities?

Answer (score 8):

Runes cannot be spent in a No Powers playthrough. Instead, every rune you pick up will automatically be converted to 200 coin.